# NullPointerExecption .getPreferences in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

.getPreferences me da un error de tipo NullPointer, me gustaria saber que debo agregar o quitar para que no se produzca este error

```
if (clicks == 17){

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity()**.getPreferences**(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("codigoSemana", 101);
    editor.apply();
    Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.calendarioFragment);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el método `onAttach()` y guarda el contexto en una variable local:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
         mContext = context;
    }
```

Cambia `getPreferences()` por `getSharedPreferences()` para usar el contexto:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```